# how to extract thesaurus file from MS Word?

Tags: text, ms-word, analytics, bigdata

I write my graduate project about semantic text analysis in big data.
I need something like synonyms dictionary to make the job.
So I decided to use the thesaurus built-in MS Word.
Does anyone know in which file MS Word store its thesaurus so I'll be able to extract it and parse and use in my program?
(I know there are many others dictionaries in the net, but I'm too lazy to retype it manually).